# Copy all, add elements in other namespace, declare namespace on root node

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have multiple XML files that could be the input for the XSLT. In these multiple input XML files I do not know all the namespaces that can be used and I do not know all the root nodes that could be used, all I know is that all elements are in one single namespace.

So my input XML could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<foo:someUnknownRoot xmlns:foo="http://anUnknownNamespace/foo">
    <foo:element>value</foo:element>
</foo:someUnknownRoot>
```

Are another could be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar:anotherUnknownRoot xmlns:bar="http://anUnknownNamespace/bar">
    <bar:element>value</bar:element>
</bar:anotherUnknownRoot>
```

I want to create a XSLT that just copies the complete input and adds elements in a own defined prefix. The namespace I like to be declared on root node.

So I would expect an output like this (one example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar:anotherUnknownRoot xmlns:bar="http://anUnknownNamespace/bar" xmlns:added="http://myAddedNamespace/added">
    <added:element>value</added:element>
    <bar:element>value</bar:element>
</bar:anotherUnknownRoot>
```

I have tried with the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:added="http://myAddedNamespace/added">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="/*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>
            <added:element>value</added:element>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But this would output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bar:anotherUnknownRoot xmlns:bar="http://anUnknownNamespace/bar">
    <added:element xmlns:added="http://myAddedNamespace/added">value</added:element>
    <bar:element>value</bar:element>
</bar:anotherUnknownRoot>
```

Ofcourse this is correct XML, but for readability I would like to add the 'added' namespace to the root node.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add

```
<xsl:namespace name="added">http://myAddedNamespace/added</xsl:namespace>
```

after `<xsl:copy>`